# Inserting id of child into the parent model Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

So here is my question: I have two schemas: Table and Order

```
schema "tables" do
field :table_number, :string
field :current_order, :integer
has_many :orders, Pos1.Order

schema "orders" do
field :number_of_customers, :integer
field :completed, :boolean, default: false
belongs_to :table, Pos1.Table
```

When I create a new order, controller just inserts the changeset and redirect to show.

```
def create(conn, %{"order" => order_params}) do
  changeset = conn.assigns[:table]
  |> build_assoc(:orders)
  |> Order.changeset(order_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, _order} ->
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Order created successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: table_order_path(conn, :show, conn.assigns[:table], _order))
  {:error, changeset} ->
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
   end
   end
```

However is it possible to insert the id of the created order into the parent(table) into the current_order field?

Additionally, when the order.completed changes to "true" value, how can i remove the id from current_order (in table)?

Basically, I am working on functionality, that if the table has current_order - it will show it onclick. If not, then it redirects to a page to create order. And ones order is created, current_order in table should be assigned.

Comment: try this - https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1114

Comment: OFF-TOPIC: I also recommend applying Elixir style guide to your code: https://github.com/niftyn8/elixir_style_guide It makes it easier to read for other people. There is even a tool that will check it for you and report all problems: https://github.com/rrrene/credo You can edit your question and format the code properly in case other people read it :)

Comment: @tkowal thanks for the link! I'll check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't fully understand your problem but is this that you want?

```
def create(conn, %{"order" => order_params}) do
  changeset = conn.assigns[:table]
  |> build_assoc(:orders)
  |> Order.changeset(order_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, order} ->

    changeset = Table.changeset(conn.assigns[:table], %{current_order: order.id})
    table     = Repo.update! changeset

    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Order created successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: table_order_path(conn, :show, conn.assigns[:table], _order))
  {:error, changeset} ->
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
   end
   end
```

Better mechanisms should be use to ensure that the insertion was successful and what to do if it wasn't (using transactions and rollbacks maybe).

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Except i changed Repo.insert! changeset to Repo.update! changeset, because it was returning "* unique: tables_pkey" error.

Comment: Yeah you're right the table already exists. I'll edit the answer then.